# Dagger: inject into different instances of one class

Tags: java, dependency-injection, nested, dagger

Can I use [Dagger](http://square.github.io/dagger/) to inject different values into several instances of the same class that are deep inside the object graph? I want to avoid passing the values through the containing objects in the graph (so I can change the implementation of the contained objects without affecting their containers).

Here's a contrived example. The object graph is a Top, which contains a Left and Right, which each contain a Show. So there are two instances of Show.

```
class Top {
  Left left;
  Right right;
  void encodeTwice(String data) {
    left.encode(data);
    right.encode(data.getBytes());
  }
}
class Left {
  Leaf leaf;
  void encode(String data) {
    leaf.write(URLEncoder.encode(data));
  }
}
class Right {
  Leaf leaf;
  void encode(byte[] data) {
    leaf.write(DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(data));
  }
}
interface Leaf {
  void write(String data);
}
class Show implements Leaf {
  String label;
  @Override public void write(String data) {
    System.out.println(label + ": " + data);
  }
}
// There might be other classes that implement Leaf.
```

Can I use Dagger to inject different values into Top.left.leaf.label and Top.right.leaf.label?

Here's one attempt. This is unsatisfactory, because Left and Right depend on the implementation of Leaf. I want to inject Show.label without involving Left or Right.

```
ObjectGraph.create(new TopModule()).get(Top.class).encodeTwice("Hello!");

@Module(injects = Top.class)
public class TopModule {
  @Provides @Named("Left.leaf.label") String provideLeftLabel() {
    return "URL encoded";
  }
  @Provides @Named("Right.leaf.label") String provideRightLabel() {
    return "Base 64";
  }
}
class Top {
  @Inject Left left;
  @Inject Right right;
  void encodeTwice(String data) {
    left.encode(data);
    right.encode(data.getBytes());
  }
}
class Left {
  Leaf leaf;
  @Inject Left(@Named("Left.leaf.label") String label) {
    leaf = new Show(label);
  }
  void encode(String data) {
    leaf.write(URLEncoder.encode(data));
  }
}
class Right {
  Leaf leaf;
  @Inject Right(@Named("Right.leaf.label") String label) {
    leaf = new Show(label);
  }
  void encode(byte[] data) {
    leaf.write(DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(data));
  }
}
interface Leaf {
  void write(String data);
}
class Show implements Leaf {
  String label;
  Show(String label) {
    this.label = label;
  }
  @Override public void write(String data) {
    System.out.println(label + ": " + data);
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but with this example you are breaking KISS principe. Could you explain why are you trying to replace with injection code of initialisation? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I aim to separate three concerns: the implementation of some re-usable code (Leaf), its use by other code (Left and Right), and initializing so it will work in each case (TopModule). I hope to use Dagger to address the third concern; that is initializing each instance. A more realistic example would have Left.leaf and Right.leaf refer to an interface which is implemented by several classes. I hope Dagger would choose the right implementation class for each use, as well as constructing and initializing an instance.

Comment: Again, from your example I don't see different implementation `Left` and `Right` are `Leaf`. That is the beauty of linked data - you can rearrange tree or shuffle linked lists without new objects creation. If you want to have additional information in leaf if it is left or right it is better to have changeable property

Comment: I guess Eugen meant the example was silly. I agree. I rewrote the question, so the example is a little more realistic and (I hope) less silly. I do want to have additional information in leaf, and I hope to use Dagger to initialize it.

Comment: I think you'll need more clarification.  What would you like the code to look like?  Are you trying to get rid of Left and Right?

Comment: The question is, can I use Dagger to inject different values into Top.left.leaf.label and Top.right.leaf.label? I'm not interested in changing the example classes Top, Left, Right, Leaf and Show, except as required to work with Dagger. (It will be necessary to add some annotations, but I hope that's sufficient.)

Answer (score 10):

So this is hard to reason about with such abstract types because based on what `Left`, `Right`, and `Top` actually are I might change approaches.

There are three approaches to this problem that I can think of: a `Leaf` factory, differentiation of `Leaf`s by qualifier, differentiation of `Leaf`s by child graphs.

#### Factory

Hide the `Leaf` implementation behind a factory that takes its required dependencies.

```
interface LeafFactory {
  Leaf create(String name);
}

class TopModule {
  // ...

  @Provide @Singleton LeafFactory provideLeafFactory() {
    return new LeafFactory() {
      @Override public Leaf create(String name) {
        return new Show(name);
      }
    };
  }
}

class Left {
  private final Leaf leaf;

  @Inject Left(@Named("..") String name, LeafFactory leafFactory) {
    leaf = leafFactory.create(name);
  }

  // ...
}
```

#### Qualifier

Right now you are injecting the label via a qualifier annotation. There's no reason you couldn't do the same thing but with `Leaf` instances.

```
class TopModule {
  @Provides @Named("..") Leaf provideLeftLeaf() {
    return new Show("URL encoded");
  }

  @Provides @Named("..") Leaf provideRightLeaf() {
    return new Show("Base64 encoded");
  }
}

class Left {
  @Inject Left(@Named("..") Leaf leftLeaf) { .. }
}
```

Note: You can still inject the label names as arguments to the `provideFooLeaf` methods if you need that abstraction as well.

#### Child Graphs

By extending the graph with a "leaf scope" you can create separate parts of your application (e.g., "right", "left") which only have a single `Leaf` instance.

```
@Module(addsTo = TopModule.class)
class LeafModule {
  private final String label;

  LeafModule(String label) {
    this.label = label;
  }

  @Provide @Singleton Leaf provideLeaf() {
    return new Show(label);
  }
}
```

Now we can `.plus()` this onto the root object graph to get a scope.

```
ObjectGraph ogRoot = ObjectGraph.create(new TopModule());
// ...
ObjectGraph ogLeft = ogRoot.plus(new LeafModule("URL encoded"));
Leaf left = ogLeft.get(Leaf.class);
ObjectGraph ogRight = ogRoot.plus(new LeafModule("Base64 encoded"));
Leaf right = ogRight.get(Leaf.class);
```

Like I said, this is hard to generalize to fit the abstract sample app you've outlined. But I hope you can see how child graphs allow you create a specialized version of the graph which is a superset of the "root" graph. By doing this multiple times you can alter the dependencies which are used to inject your types.

Comment: The 'Factory' suggestion is unsatisfactory, because the label is passed through Left and Right (which means Left and Right would have to change to support a different Leaf implementation class with different dependecies). The 'Qualifier' suggestion doesn't use Dagger to inject into Show (the injection is done by TopModule, not by Dagger). The 'Child Graphs' suggestion doesn't work: ogRoot.plus(new LeafModule(...)) throws java.lang.IllegalStateException: Errors creating object graph: Leaf could not be bound with key Leaf required by class Left.

Answer (score 0):

Jake has presented great examples of different options. From my understanding, the label is really defined by the Left or Right classes. You can move the field to those classes and pass them to the Leaf. If you want a label-less Leaf you could extend the interface to with LabeledLeaf, then Left and Right could instanceof  LabeledLeaf to decide if they should use the labeled write method.

Your sample setup actually sounds a lot like [Timber](https://github.com/JakeWharton/timber). You should consider seeing how we get `Tree`s that are able to write to different outputs based on their implementation, and some are able to be labeled. A difference in the end result, is that Timber's API is static methods, not a component you inject into classes.

Comment: No, I aim to inject the label without involving Left or Right. To motivate this, imagine another application that constructs a similar object graph, but with Leaf implemented by a different class with different dependencies. For example, a class Output that depends on an OutputStream, a class Store that depends on a File or a class Send that depends on a Socket. It seems impractical to make Left and Right handle any of these alternatives. I aim to initialize the objects elsewhere and inject them into Left and Right (using Dagger, I hope).

Comment: @JohnKristian, my point is that you're defining the label based on where the Leaf is injected, meaning it actually is defined by "belonging to Left" or "belonging to Right". They don't have to care about the implementation of Leaf, only that they are giving it a label.

Comment: @JohnKristian, I added a comment about Timber to my answer, might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Dagger can do this, if you create a separate ObjectGraph for each instance of the injected class. To provide a complete graph, a module can implement @Provides methods that delegate to the subgraphs. Thanks to Jake Wharton for a suggestion that pushed me toward this technique.

Here's an example:

```
LeafModule leftLeaf = new ShowModule("URL encoded");
LeafModule rightLeaf = new ShowModule("Base 64");
ObjectGraph top = ObjectGraph.create(new TopModule(leftLeaf, rightLeaf));
top.get(Top.class).encodeTwice("Hello!");

@Module(injects = Top.class)
class TopModule {
  TopModule(LeafModule leftLeaf, LeafModule rightLeaf) {
    leftGraph = ObjectGraph.create(leftLeaf).plus(new MiddleModule());
    rightGraph = ObjectGraph.create(rightLeaf).plus(new MiddleModule());
  }
  private final ObjectGraph leftGraph;
  private final ObjectGraph rightGraph;
  @Provides Left getLeft() {
    return leftGraph.get(Left.class);
  }
  @Provides Right getRight() {
    return rightGraph.get(Right.class);
  }
  @Module(injects = {Left.class, Right.class},
          complete = false /* doesn't inject Leaf */)
  static class MiddleModule {
  }
}
/** A Dagger module that can provide a Leaf. */
interface LeafModule {
}
@Module(injects = Leaf.class)
class ShowModule implements LeafModule {
  ShowModule(String showLabel) {
    label = showLabel;
  }
  private final String label;
  @Provides @Named("Show.label") String getLabel() {
    return label;
  }
  @Provides Leaf provideLeaf(Show implementation) {
    return implementation;
  }
}
class Top {
  @Inject Left left;
  @Inject Right right;
  void encodeTwice(String data) {
    left.encode(data);
    right.encode(data.getBytes());
  }
}
class Left {
  @Inject Leaf leaf;
  void encode(String data) {
    leaf.write(URLEncoder.encode(data));
  }
}
class Right {
  @Inject Leaf leaf;
  void encode(byte[] data) {
    leaf.write(DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(data));
  }
}
interface Leaf {
  void write(String data);
}
class Show implements Leaf {
  @Inject @Named("Show.label") String label;
  @Override public void write(String data) {
    System.out.println(label + ": " + data);
  }
}
```